# Shortest path in a giant graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory, shortest-path

Nowadays I study on graphs that usually don't fit into any type of memory or storage devices. And my problem is that I need to find a shortest path between two particular vertices in such graphs.

I aware of boost graph library for C++ and I'm a big fun of it. Usual concept to use boost's graph library (and others as well) is that

1. create vertex list in the memory
2. create edge connectivity list in the memory
3. call the graph algorithm that you desire

This approach works well for graphs which fit into RAM:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS,
    vecS,
    undirectedS,
    no_property,
    property<edge_weight_t, uint32_t> 
> TGraph;

void FindShortestPath(const TGraph& g, const uint32_t from, const uint32_t to)
{
    vector<TGraph::edge_descriptor> path;
    TGraph::vertex_descriptor v = vertex(to, g); // We want to start at the destination and work our way back to the source


    vector<TGraph::vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
    vector<uint32_t> d(num_vertices(g));

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, vertex(from, g),
                            predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)))
                            .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(vertex_index, g))));

    for(auto u = p[v]; u != v; v = u, u = p[v])
    {
        path.push_back(edge(u, v, g).first);
    }

    //// Write shortest path
    cout << "Distance: " << d[to] << endl;
    for(auto i = path.rbegin() + 1; i != path.rend(); ++i)
    {
        cout << source(*i, g) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

But since my graph is huge, above approach doesn't suit my requirements. The graph that I study currently has 16! vertices and each vertices have same degree which is 64. And also, what I believe that maximum of shortest distances between any vertex pairs is less than 20.

Well the good thing about the graph is that it's vertices and edges are mathematically perfectly defined. With that knowledge, It shouldn't be necessary to create whole graph in the memory apriori to run certain shortest path algorithms on it.

My idea is that there should be a way of doing that with boost library, whenever I need to provide edge connections of a specific vertex, I can provide or calculate it instantly by using this mathematical definition, only at the time of shortest path calculation when it is necessary and then once job finishes, release it.

I'm stuck here and it is beyond my boost library or shortest path algorithm implementation knowledge.

1. Do you think that above dynamic approach is possible with boost graph library? If yes, how? Please provide some examples or documentations.
2. Do you think that if I implement shortest path algorithm with dynamic approach, is there a chance to solve shortest path in acceptable times comparing to create whole graph in memory and than running the algorithm?
3. If "1" is not possible but "2" is, then what do you suggest to go with?

Thanks.